# Alterar seta do select ao acionar o evento clique

Tags: css, css3

Bom, tenho o select abaixo:

```
<div class="selectOptions">
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

E o `CSS` abaixo que `adiciona` uma `seta para baixo` como `background` da `div` `selectOptions` e `encobre` a seta original do `select`

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.selectOptions {
    width: 240px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.selectOptions select {
    display: block !important;
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Tentei adicionar o código abaixo mas não funcionou.

```
.selectOptions:hover {  
    background: url(../_imgs/setaCima.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
}
```

Na verdade funcionou sim, mas é preciso clicar no botão e não apenas passar o mouse por cima para que o select abra.

Alguma ideia de **como trocar a seta do select quando o mesmo for aberto?**
Ou seja, apenas durante o tempo de abertura e depois retorna naturalmente à **setaBaixo.jpg**

Comment: Podes colocar aqui a imagem dessa seta? (de uma delas)

Comment: Sim,: http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/   ultimo elemento do form, lá embaixo da pagina

Comment: Carlos, não é possivel abrir o select nativo com mousehover, nem mudar imagem quando estiver aberto pois não há controlos nativos para isso. Terias de fazer/usar um custom select que imite um select.

Comment: ta bom obrigado. Mas se alguém tiver outra ideia...agradeço

Comment: Tem um exemplos bem legais [Custom Select Elements](https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index.html) vou pode adaptar para seu projeto.